# Remove the embed option from iframe video player

Tags: iframe, brightcove

I have the following iframe that is used to embed a video using the BrightCove video player.  When the video is embedded on another website, the player shows the embed code and video link. How can I remove them so player that is embedded does not show the embed code as a control option?

```
<div style="position:relative;height:0;padding-bottom:56.25%;padding-top:25px;">
  <iframe style="position:absolute;height:100%;width:100%;top:0;left:0;"
          frameborder="0" allowfullscreen 
          src="https://my.domain.com/videoframe/12345/my-video">
  </iframe>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Uncheck "display player embed code" from the player's social settings.

https://player.support.brightcove.com/plugins/social-sharing-plugin.html

Comment: I need something to pass in the iframe.  Do you know how I can modify the code above to prevent the embed and link?

Comment: You can re-initialise the social plugin, and you can access the current settings. Within your iframe page you could do `player.socialSettings.removeEmbed = true; player.social(player.socialSettings);` condititionally based on some query string param on the iframe source.

Comment: how do I identify the player object? "player" does not seem to work when I try it.

Comment: https://player.support.brightcove.com/coding-topics/overview-player-api.html

Comment: Where do I set the player Id on the Iframe? “var myPlayer = videojs.getPlayer('myPlayerID');” do I just add the Id to the Iframe?